# Attaching Command to ScrollViewer.ScrollChanged of ListView

Tags: wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light, eventtrigger, eventtocommand

The WPF `ListView` class can be set up to automatically handle scrolling without an external `ScrollViewer` and it's possible to register an event handler for the control's internal scrollbar by writing XAML like such:

```
<ListView ScrollViewer.ScrollChanged="ScrollChanged"  />
```

How to attach it to MVVM light Command? I tried the following, but it doesn't work:

```
<ListView>
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="ScrollViewer.ScrollChangedEvent">
            <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding ScrollCommand}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</ListView>
```

Note: `ScrollCommand` - is a `RelayCommand` from my viewmodel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`EventTrigger` doesn't trigger for routed events. You can use the solution proposed in [this article](http://joyfulwpf.blogspot.co.il/2009/05/mvvm-invoking-command-on-attached-event.html)
to create a `RoutedEventTrigger` class and use it instead of `EventTrigger`.

Comment: thanks, it's very useful, but now I have another problem : I can't get any args from it.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend a Behavior for this. If you don't have Blend, you'll need to get the Blend SDK. But once you have that, you can follow [this tutorial](http://wpftutorial.net/Behaviors.html) to extend the behavior of the ScrollViewer.

Comment: You're using *a* behavior, the EventToCommand behavior. But you can write a custom one that searches for the ListView's ScrollViewer and hooks up to the "ScrolledChanged" event. You can also add a DependencyProperty on the behavior that allows you to bind a command. In the event handler you can invoke the command you're binding to.